# ExtJs Border Around Control Box Only, Not Label

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc

I have an EXTJS TimePicker control. I want to add a border around the picker box itself, not the label or overall panel just the box when the user clicks in the field. I have the follow code the provides a partial solution. It used to work when the label was to the left of the control. Once I moved the label to the top I get the incorrect behavior:

```
function txtTimeCtr_Focus(sender, event, eOpts )
{
 //Change the border color to red to show the time is no longer running
 sender.getPicker().pickerField.getEl().addCls('txtTime-focus-border');
 //sender.getEl().addCls('txtTime-focus-border');
}
```

Here is a screen shot of what I am currently receiving

[image]:

This is the functionality I need to obtain:

[image]

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Sidenote, `sender === sender.getPicker().pickerField`, right?

Comment: #evan-trimboli ExtJs 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the style on the `triggerWrap`:

```
var f = new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
    renderTo: document.body
});
f.triggerWrap.setStyle('border', '1px solid red');
```

Comment: Evan that worked great. Thank you so much. Now once the user clicks a button I need to remove that style. Can I do that easily as well? @Evan Trimboli